# shell scripting - file existence

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I want to ask a question on shell scripting 
Suppose there are two paths on which a file may be installed
`Path_1` or `Path_2`

The script first should look for the file on `Path_1` 
if the file is not present or installed on `Path_1` 
then the script should look for the file on `path_2` 
if its not there too then show the **error**

i have this
code:-`# Make sure that sh.exe is found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe
ls /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin/sh.exe > /dev/null 2>&1 || {
    echo
    echo -e "\t Git Bash was not installed in the default location."
    echo -e '\t Installation requires sh.exe to be found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\\bin\sh.exe.'
    echo
    echo -e "\e[0;31mAborting...\e[m"
    waitForEnterAndExit
}
echo -e "\t Git Bash installation found in C:\Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe"`

now the sh.exe can be installed at

C:\Program Files\Git\bin

**or**

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe
```

now i want to change the script so that it checks for the file first at

C:\Program Files\Git\bin

if the file is not there  then at

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe
```

Comment: What did you do yourself to find the anwer?

Comment: Try Googling `"bash file exists"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple sample code you can deploy, and be sure to modify the values of Path_1 & Path_2.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                  

Path_1="path1"
Path_2="path2"

Filename=$1

[ -z ${Filename} ] && echo Filename cannot be empty && exit -1

[ -e ${Path_1}/${Filename} ] && echo Found ${Filename} under ${Path_1} && exit 0
[ -e ${Path_2}/${Filename} ] && echo Found ${Filename} under ${Path_2} && exit 0

echo ${Filename} cannot be found under ${Path_1} and ${Path_2} && exit -1
```

Comment: I need to change the value of filename too . Right??

Comment: No need to modify the Filename in the script. Filename is the first parameter of the script, usage: `./script Filename`